# Angular Material 2: Sidenav has no backdrop

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-material2

I am currently developing an **Angular 2** site and having some trouble with the SideNav component.

The **SideNav** can have 3 modes, none of which seem to change what happens when I open the Sidenav. I am trying to get the backdrop to display after opening.

The sideNav does open, however the backdrop doesn' t show up.

The root of the app is the **md-sidenav container**. The `SideBar` component will also be passed to the `NavBar` component as the open button is defined in there.

Note that I have also tried to bring the `SideBar` component outside the `<md-sidenav-container>`

```
<md-sidenav-container>
    <sidebar #sideBarComponent></sidebar>
    <navbar [sideBar]=sideBarComponent></navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

The SidNnav currently contains 2 links and is set to mode "*over*" (which should create a SideNav and backdrop over the main content)

```
<md-sidenav #sideBar mode="over">
    <md-nav-list>
        <a md-list-item routerLink="/home" (click)="sideBar.close()" routerLinkActive="active-link">
            <md-icon md-list-icon>home</md-icon>
            <p md-line>Home</p>
        </a>
        <a md-list-item routerLink="/users" (click)="sideBar.close()" routerLinkActive="active-link">
            <md-icon md-list-icon>account_circle</md-icon>
            <p md-line>Users</p>
        </a>
    </md-nav-list>
</md-sidenav>
```

Inspecting the page using chrome's developer tools reveals that a backdrop is created (`<div class="md-sidenav-backdrop"></div>`) and covering the whole page, however it is set to hidden and has no effect due to not having a functional CSS applied to it. (only set fixed width, height and position, nothing visible that alters the page)

The prebuild-css has a background color tag for it, however it needs a `.md-sidenav-shown`:

```
.md-sidenav-backdrop.md-sidenav-shown {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)
}
```

Is there anything that would cause this behavior to happen?
None of the tutorials and examples I found did something complicated so I think it is due to my set-up.

Relevant Libraries and versions (All webjars):

```
Angular 2.4.1
   common
   core
   compiler
   forms
   http
   platform-browser
   platform-browser-dynamic
   router
Angular-Material 2.0.0-Beta.1
SystemJs 0.19.41
Core-js 2.4.1
Reflect-Metadata 0.1.8
Typescript 2.1.4
RxJs 5.0.1
HammerJS 2.0.6
Zone.js 0.7.4
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you cannot put `md-sidenav` inside component because there is no link between `md-sidenav-container` and child `md-sidenav`'s. `Md-sidenav-container` uses `@ContentChildren` to access `md-sidenav` instances.

So there must be direct parent-child relation between `md-sidenav-container` and `md-sidenav`.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the scope of CSS defined in `your.component.css` limited to only that component, Angular processes the CSS/SCSS/SASS files and adds "attribute" selectors to each CSS rule defined in that file.

In your case, it converts your `.md-sidenav-backdrop.md-sidenav-shown {...}` CSS rule into something like:

```
.md-sidenav-backdrop.md-sidenav-shown[_ngcontent-xyh-65] {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)
}
```

Angular is strict about restricting the scope. The trouble is that the backdrop `<div class="md-sidenav-backdrop"></div>` is added by the material component (at browser render time, I presume). Hence, the selector suffix `[_ngcontent-xyh-65]` is not added to that element at compile time.

The only way around it, that I could find till now, is to move your CSS to `<root>/src/styles.css`.
**UPDATE:** As Rose suggests, it would be safest to have your component name selector prefixed to the CSS you add in `styles.css`. In your case:

```
md-sidenav-container > .md-sidenav-backdrop.md-sidenav-shown {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)
}
```

Comment: One addition: In order to allow different components to override the same style differently, prefix the CSS selector that you've moved to styles.css (or index.html) with the component's element tag. For example: `my-component .md-sidenav-backdrop { ... }`